# how to add dependency of the latest springframework (5.3.17)

Tags: spring

this is my dependency in xml file

```
 `<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
`
```

so there is any problem in the verson? i use this verson becauese it is the lastest verson in the spring website

[image]

of course i also try other verson like 5.2.6.in the intel IDEA ,it can add the what i need ,but if i use 5.3.17 as verson ,i meet the 无法解析 org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.17.RELEASE . please give me some help .
thank you

Comment: Which artifact repository are you using? The mentioned artifact is available on the maven repository. If your app is configured to download the artifact from there then you shouldn't face the issue.
`https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.